# LastModifiedBy User Name not populating inside Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, salesforcedx, case

I am having this code inside my after insert trigger code block.

```
   if(Trigger.isInsert && Trigger.isAfter) {

   List <History__c> historyRecords = new List<History__c>();
    History__c newhistory = new History__c();
    for(Case cs: trigger.new)
    {
      newhistory.Name='New Case Opened';
      newhistory.Modified_by_User__c=cs.LastModifiedBy.Name;
      newhistory.Time_and_Date__c=cs.CreatedDate;
      newhistory.Case_Number__c=cs.CaseNumber;
      historyRecords.add(newhistory);
    }
     insert historyRecords;
    }
```

The problem is when new record gets created, the LastModifiedBy.Name is coming as null. Same logic when I tried from Anonymous Code block, was working fine. Why is it happening so?

Comment: The gist is that if you need to use more than one dot/period/full-stop to access the data, it is not available in trigger context variables (and you need to query for it). The canonical-qa question I marked this as a duplicate of goes over it in more detail.

Comment: Also note that the line `History__c newhistory = new History__c();` should be inside the `for(Case cs: trigger.new)` loop. You need a new instance of the object for each insert.